# Facebook Group Post Scraping Using Selenium Only Returns One Post

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, web-scraping

I'm in the process of building a Facebook Group Scraper, I have managed to write the code to log-in + scrape the name of the, but for some reason, my code is only returning one result and not all of the posts of the page as I would like it to.

Here's my code:

```
for result in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb fhuww2h9 hpfvmrgz gile2uim pwa15fzy g5gj957u aov4n071 oi9244e8 bi6gxh9e h676nmdw aghb5jc5"]'):
    poster = result.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="oajrlxb2 g5ia77u1 qu0x051f esr5mh6w e9989ue4 r7d6kgcz rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 nc684nl6 p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x jb3vyjys rz4wbd8a qt6c0cv9 a8nywdso i1ao9s8h esuyzwwr f1sip0of lzcic4wl oo9gr5id gpro0wi8 lrazzd5p"]/strong/span').text
    description = result.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x c1et5uql ii04i59q"]').text

    groupcomments.append({
        'poster' : poster,
        'description' : description,
    })

    print(groupcomments)
```

Here's a snippet of the Facebook Source code (you can find it yourself over here: https://www.facebook.com/groups/286175922122417)

```
<div data-pagelet="GroupFeed"><div class="j83agx80 l9j0dhe7 k4urcfbm"><div class="rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb hybvsw6c io0zqebd m5lcvass fbipl8qg nwvqtn77 k4urcfbm ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs sbcfpzgs" style="border-radius: max(0px, min(8px, ((100vw - 4px) - 100%) * 9999)) / 8px;"><div class="ihqw7lf3"><div class="rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb j83agx80 cbu4d94t pfnyh3mw d2edcug0 e5nlhep0 aodizinl"><div class="rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb j83agx80 cbu4d94t buofh1pr tgvbjcpo"><div class="rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb j83agx80 cbu4d94t pfnyh3mw d2edcug0 hv4rvrfc dati1w0a"><div class="j83agx80 cbu4d94t ew0dbk1b irj2b8pg"><div class="qzhwtbm6 knvmm38d"><span class="d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b c1et5uql oi732d6d ik7dh3pa ht8s03o8 a8c37x1j keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d9wwppkn fe6kdd0r mau55g9w c8b282yb iv3no6db a5q79mjw g1cxx5fr lrazzd5p oo9gr5id" dir="auto"><div class="rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb j83agx80 pfnyh3mw i1fnvgqd bp9cbjyn owycx6da btwxx1t3 jeutjz8y"><div class="rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb j83agx80 cbu4d94t g5gj957u d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz rj1gh0hx buofh1pr"
```

Any ideas to get all the info I'm looking for? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. And you are aware that those classnames changes all the time. They may not even be the same when you scrape them and you load it in the browser.

Comment: Hmm,  thanks for the heads-up, I've been told that it's possible but maybe it isn't anymore... So far I've used different browsers to test it and it seems that class names remain the same, which led me to believe that there was a way to scrape the site.

Comment: @monicab did you tried this https://github.com/kevinzg/facebook-scraper

Comment: i have done it by selenium but for scraping the links of the posts

Comment: @krishnan thanks for the tip! could you share the code you're using as well? I have to install the script and run it but I keep getting an error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to scrape what I wanted using the BeautifulSoup HTML scraper to simply scrape the information using the xpath of the info I was looking for (this not 100% foolproof solution as those can change, but it can easily be replaced in the code, so I guess it's better than nothing...)

```
while True:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
    all_posts=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"du4w35lb k4urcfbm l9j0dhe7 sjgh65i0"})
    for post in all_posts:
        try:
            name=post.find("a",{"class":"oajrlxb2 g5ia77u1 qu0x051f esr5mh6w e9989ue4 r7d6kgcz rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 nc684nl6 p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x jb3vyjys rz4wbd8a qt6c0cv9 a8nywdso i1ao9s8h esuyzwwr f1sip0of lzcic4wl oo9gr5id gpro0wi8 lrazzd5p"}).get_text()
        except:
            name="not found"
        print(name)
```

If you want a more in-depth tutorial, I also made a video showing how I wrote it, [you can watch it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDBho83SUrw) (you'll find the complete code in the video description as well)

Answer (score 0):

//make enough scroll

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(2)
```

//and repeat scrapping

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).